# Android - RecyclerView add item to firstPosition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using [RecyclerViewPager](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager). On `OnPageChangedListener` in `onPageChanged` I'm adding item to the left or to the right depending to the swipe direction.

```
public void addLeft() {

    int index = dataSet.size() - 1;

    dataSet.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);

    dataSet.add(0, new Data());
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

The thing is, I can scroll to the left to infinity, but `onBindViewHolder` is not called, even when calling `notifyItemInserted`. Could you tell me what could help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution `setHasStableIds(false)`